# Angularjs - Retain the entered form data during redirection for the user to continue when coming back to that form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am creating a simple user data collection project which requires the user to enter data in multiple forms.

I have created separate html page for each form.

There are forms for the user to enter personal details, educational details and a few more.

When a user enters personal details and clicks `next` I store the data in localstorage and in the end all the data are sent to db.

When the user clicks `next` and again comes to the same page i retrieve the data from localstorage and bind it in the respective text boxes. But when the user does not click `next` and goes to another page by using the nav bar options the entered data is lost.

But I want the to data to be there even if the user does not click `next` and go to another page and come back to that page so that he can continue to fill the form where he left.

I am doing this project in Angularjs.

I have got no clue on how to do this, someone pls put me on the right track.

```
angular.module('userDetails').factory('sessionService', [function () {
return{
    getGlobal: function(key){
        var data = localStorage.getItem("user."+ key);
        if(data){
            return JSON.parse(data).data;
        }
        return null;
    },
    get : function(key){
        var data = localStorage.getItem("user."+ key);
        if(data){
            return JSON.parse(data).data;
        }
        return null;
    },
    set: function(key, value){
        localStorage.setItem("user."+key, JSON.stringify({data: value}));
    }
};

}]);
```

In my html

```
<button ng-click=savePD(PD)> Next </button>
```

When the `next` button is clicked in personal details form:

```
$scope.savePD = function(PD){
    sessionService.set("personalData",PD);
    $location.path('/educationData');
}
```

So when the `next` button is clicked the model values are passed to the function and then stored in local.

So I need to know when I don't click next and go to another page how do i retain the currently entered value in the first form.

Comment: Are you using angular router to navigate to next page.?
If so you can use `$location.path()` to decide which date to load in the form

Comment: Does all the forms from the same controller?

Comment: @Sravan No different controller for each form

Comment: ok, please add few code, minimum the logic you implemented to store inlocal storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$rootscope` if you do not want your data to be lost in the page navigation.

The data in `rootscope` can be accessed through any controller, `just inject the rootscope in the controller`.

Root scope should be initialized in the `app.run` function.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.form_data = {}
})
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

})
.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {

});
```

`form_data` is available in every form in any controller as a hash.

Form 1,

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="form_data.firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="form_data.lastName">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Form 2,

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
  <form>
    Profile:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="form_data.profile"><br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="number" ng-model="form_data.age">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="next()">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Now you can retrieve the values from the rootscope from the last controller and send it to db.

```
.controller('myCtrl3', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  var data = $rootScope.form_data

  // call http using a service or here itself and send data as a parameter
});
```

Comment: pls check my ans once.

Comment: yeah trying to implement that.. just thought you could give me an idea where i went wrong in mine

Comment: which router you are using for navigation?